# Regex pattern yields different results on almost identical input strings

Tags: c#, regex

Why do I get different behaviors for similar search strings on the same pattern?

Note the below was written by a colleague, not myself.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/veyasw

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{

    static void MatchTest(string input, string pattern)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pattern: " + pattern);
        Console.WriteLine("input: " + input + Environment.NewLine);
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

        if (match.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("Match '{0}' at index {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not match");

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n------\r\n");

    }

    static void DiffBehaviousTest() // (?(expression)yes) has different behavious. Sometime it matches with string empty.
    {
        /* if last character in word is digit
                match ab
        */
        string pattern = @"(?(.*\d\b)ab)";

        MatchTest("xy xya", pattern);
        MatchTest("xy xyz", pattern);
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        DiffBehaviousTest();
    }
}
```

which yields:

```
pattern: (?(.*\d\b)ab)
input: xy xya

Match '' at index 5

------

pattern: (?(.*\d\b)ab)
input: xy xyz

Not match

------
```

**Background reading**:
Here's an example of [a conditional regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe(v=vs.110).aspx#Conditional_Expr) `(?(expression)yes|no)` - if it matches expression, it looks for `yes` pattern, otherwise it looks for no pattern.  However here we don't provide the `no` case pattern.

Here's [an example of a regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition) (search for: `(?(Open)(?!))$`) that doesn't use the |no condition mentioned above.

Comment: Where is the '|' character?

Comment: @jdweng: The documentation linked to lists it as optional, but does not say what happens if it is missing.

Comment: Try this: (?(.+\d\b)y) (http://regexstorm.net/tester). Note that it matches both y's in xy xya. It probably has to do with the behavior of omitting | as (?(.+\d\b)y|fail) gives me no matches.

Comment: Optional false means nothing will be output if the condition is not met.

Comment: Since it sounds like it might be a bug, I've posted this to MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9d4aebe-1b5d-48da-9cc6-ea6f3599c02d/regex-pattern-yields-different-results-on-almost-identical-input-strings?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 2):

Exhibit A:

```
    string pattern = @"(?(.*\d\b)agarbage)";

    MatchTest("xy xya", pattern);
    MatchTest("xy xyb", pattern);
```

> pattern: (?(.*\d\b)agarbage)
>      input: xy xya
>
> Match '' at index 5
>
> ---
>
> pattern: (?(.*\d\b)agarbage)
>      input: xy xyb
>
> Not match
>
> ---

Exhibit B:

```
    string pattern = @"(?(.*\d\b)bgarbage)";

    MatchTest("xy xya", pattern);
    MatchTest("xy xyb", pattern);
```

> pattern: (?(.*\d\b)bgarbage)
>      input: xy xya
>
> Not match
>
> ---
>
> pattern: (?(.*\d\b)bgarbage)
>      input: xy xyb
>
> Match '' at index 5
>
> ---

It's behaving as if, without the `|`, it matches the first character of "yes" as the "yes".

With this, we get Not match/Not match:

```
    string pattern = @"(?(.*\d)agarbage|bgarbage)";

    MatchTest("xy xya", pattern);
    MatchTest("xy xyb", pattern);
```

And with this, we get Match 'b' at index 5:

```
    string pattern = @"(?(.*\d)a|b)";

    MatchTest("xy xya", pattern);
    MatchTest("xy xyb", pattern);
```

I (hesitantly) think there may be a bug in the parser in the no-pipe case. But @EricLippert is here, and I'm more interested in his view than in my own.

Comment: I found the same and agree.

Comment: I know nothing about the regular expression parser. I agree that this looks at least superficially like a bug. I find the regular expression documentation to be less precise than I would prefer, so it is hard to say with justification what the right behaviour is, but this does not look like the right behaviour to me.